# JAVA how to refer the file in Project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, apache-flink, embedded-resource

I am create a simple Java Project in my VS Code, and here is the project structure.
[image]

I want to refer the `wordcount.txt` in my code, but it fail to find the file.

Here is my test code:

```
public class BatchJob {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // set up the batch execution environment
    final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    //URL url = BatchJob.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/wordcount.txt");
    DataSource<String> dataset = env.readTextFile("wordcount.txt");
    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> result = dataset.flatMap(new Tokenizer())
                                                    .filter(new FilterFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>>(){
                                                        @Override
                                                        public boolean filter(Tuple2<String, Integer> arg0){
                                                            return arg0.f1 >0;
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                    .groupBy(0)
                                                    .sum(1);
                                                    result.print();
    
}
public static class Tokenizer implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>{
    @Override
    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
        String[] tokens = value.toLowerCase().split(",");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if ( !token.isEmpty() && token.length() > 0) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(token, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is the current working directory when you execute your Java program?

Comment: Did you try providing the Complete or Full path of the File ?

Comment: Looks like your text file is in the same folder/package as your class BatchJob. Therefore you should access your resource with getResource("wordcount.txt")

Comment: @Sascha *"you should access your resource with getResource("wordcount.txt")"* That is correct. ***If*** the IDE includes such files in the final Jar that is produced on building the application. The reason for caution is that most IDEs require non-Java source (class) files to be in a specific path in order to be included. For Eclipse and Netbeans, that would be `resources/` (from memory).

Comment: @rioV8 I start this project from VS Code, the entry point is `BatchJob.main`

Comment: @Abra The error is the file could not be found. This project is Java Flink project. and this is a template for Java Flink. `ExecutionEnvironment` and `readTextFile` are all built-in code.

Comment: @Sascha What you mean by full path? I tried my physic path, and works.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for your work, work with `getResource`. Here is the working code`  URL url = BatchJob.class.getClassLoader().getResource("wordcount.txt");
  DataSource<String> dataset = env.readTextFile(URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(),"UTF-8") );`

Comment: the Java files are compiled for the JVM, then some program (`java`) (the JVM) executes this compiled code, what is the working directory of this program

Comment: @Edward. Can you share the solution as the answer for others to know it works for this question?

Comment: @MollyWang Thanks for the suggestion, I will wait `AndrewThompson` to post first, if he did not post the answer, I will share again in short days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) **must be accessed by URL rather than file**.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

> Thanks for your work, work with `getResource`. Here is the working
> code
>
> ```
> URL url = BatchJob.class.getClassLoader().getResource("wordcount.txt"); 
> DataSource<String> dataset = env.readTextFile(
>     URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(),"UTF-8") );
> ```

Unfortunately, this fix goes wrong at `url.getFile()`.

Harking back to the **bold** part of the original advice.. *".. **must** be accessed by URL rather than file"*: This is not a suggestion or merely a good programming practice, it is a requirement. The thing is, once the app. is built, the resource will be inside a Jar and will *not* be a `File` any longer. It will not be *accessible* as a `File`. So while it might work when running it from the IDE (when the URL points to something that **is a** file), it will fail for the built Jar.