# no icon shows on java swing in linux ubunutu

Tags: java, linux, swing, ubuntu

I copied the path of the image but no icon appears click on the image to see
[no icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCUQZ.png)
I created simple frame and needed to include icon

```java
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Color;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setTitle("JFrame title goes here"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit out of app
        frame.setResizable(false); // prevent frame from being resized
        frame.setSize(700,700); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        try {
            URL resource = frame.getClass().getResource("/games.png");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(resource);
            frame.setIconImage(image);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(123,50,250));
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please load the image from resources instead of from a specific system path. 
Here is an example of how to load an icon properly https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-change-jframe-image-icon/

Comment: `webp` is not a support image format, from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) *"containing a supported image format, such as GIF, JPEG, or (as of 1.3) PNG."*

Comment: Normally I would recommend using `ImageIO.load` to load you images, as it will throw an exception if the image can't be read, but, by default, it only supports *"GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP"* out of the box - however, `ImageIO` supports a pluggable framework and there are a number of [3rd party libraries which can add support for them](https://www.google.com/search?q=imageio+webp&rlz=1C5GCEM_enAU1020AU1020&oq=imageio+webp&aqs=chrome..69i57.2040j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I converted the image to png and added it to vscode project file and still did not appear

Comment: `new ImageIcon("games.png")` is expecting to find a file called `games.png` within the current working directory, which unlikely to you be source/binary location. 1.  Make use of `Class#getResource` to load embedded resources. 2. Make use of `ImageIO.load` instead of `ImageIcon` to load you images, it will throw an `Exception` when the image can't be loaded. 3. Ensure that image is within the class path of your IDE.  This is tricky and is depended on your IDEs configuration

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you think of the changes I made...but still same problem

Comment: Where is the image stored (relative to the source directory) - maybe [JAVA how to refer the file in Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901604/java-how-to-refer-the-file-in-project) can help

Comment: @MadProgrammer you can check the photo in the question it shows where the image stored

Comment: Either use a relative path of `frame.getClass().getResource("games.png")` or an absolute path of `frame.getClass().getResource("/home/salma/Downloads/games.png")` - but I'm guessing as I don't use vscode

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's not working but thank you for your time really appreciate it.